# Capistrano can't get git to work

Tags: git, capistrano3

I've added my a deploy.pub key to deploy keys on the github repo, but for some reason `cap <env> deploy` gives me this error. Also I can't clone the repo when i'm on the server, I get the permissions error. If I ssh-add my key on the server then I can clone, but running `cap <env> deploy` locally creates a new connection and the key is no longer in the keychain. What am I missing?

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
capistrano (3.4.0)
```

deploy.rb contains:

```
set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  auth_methods: %w[publickey],
  keys: %w[~/.ssh/my_local_rsa]
 }
```

The Error:

> cap aborted!
>
> SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@server.com: git exit status: 128
>
> git stdout: Nothing written
>
> git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: You probably need to start ssh agent locally and add your key, then run capistrano within that session.

Comment: Do I need to write a task to do this? If so, why isn't that in the docs? If not, that seems odd sense I would have to do that every time I deploy.

Answer (score 2):

It started working when I added the following to my `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host mydomain.com
  ForwardAgent yes
```

I also ran `ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_local_rsa`